# Undo function on bitmap is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a drawing app but facing some undo problems. When i paint into the image and then press the undo button it won't undo my last action. I'm stuck on it. I'm using floodfill algorithm.
[Here is the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xfcP.png)
Look at the Undo function in the code below, i think i did it right but please check it and tell me where is the actual problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnTouchListener {
Button red, blue, yellow, undo;
Paint paint;
private RelativeLayout drawingLayout;
private MyView myView;
private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    drawingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    drawingLayout.addView(myView);

    red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_red);
    blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_blue);
    yellow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_yellow);
    undo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.undo);

    red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

    yellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }
    });
    blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    undo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.onClickUndo();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    return false;
}


public class MyView extends View {

    final Point p1 = new Point();
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Canvas canvas;
    private Path path;


    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.gp1_1).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        this.path = new Path();


    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size()>0)  {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
        invalidate();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getString(R.string.nomore), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

}

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p1.x = (int) x;
                p1.y = (int) y;
                final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
                new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
                paths.add(path);

                invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage(getString(R.string.wait));
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

public class FloodFill {
    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor,
                          int replacementColor) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;
        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;

                }
                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow down the problem at all? At the moment this is "debug this for me", and presently your readers don't really know what the issue is, other than "it does not work". That is not very clear.

Comment: ^ Please delete your code comment and **edit it into the question**, thanks.

Comment: Please help me i updated the post